# Could not find IOException in intellij's Auto-Completing

Tags: intellij-idea

I remember once upon a time, there's one one popup window and I choose IOException. But I don't remember what's this window, maybe in this window I filter IOException so that I can not find it in auto completing. anyone know how to solve this ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean the following setting?

*File | Settings | Editor | General | Auto Import | Exclude from import and Completion*